# Xquery with multiple value element

Tags: xml, xquery

example i have xml data like this

```
<a>
   <book id="bk1">
         <test>Yeah</test>
   </book>
   <book id="bk2">
         <test>Hellow</test>
   </book>
   <book id="bk3">
         <test>yaya</test>
         <test>love</test>
         <test>hello</test>
   </book>
 </a>
```

my question is using xquery to select the book id where test element doesn't contain any value="love"

expected output:

```
<book id="bk1"/>
<book id="bk2"/>
```

but my output is like :

```
<book id="bk1"/>
<book id="bk2"/>
<book id="bk3"/>
```

following code:

```
for $b in /a
let $i := $b/book/test
let $id := $b/book/@id
where $i != "love"
return <book id="@id"/>
```

i suspect it's go to looping for bk3 and found another test value which is not love and return it. how to solve it?

Comment: This is no well-formed XML, the `<book/>` elements must be closed. Is this really the input you're given?

Comment: edited. sorry for that , i just simply type here

Comment: Never retype code or input, _always_ copy it. Makes it much too easy to introduce minor mistakes that lead to long ping-pong debugging in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is returning a single, empty element for me. Instead of looping over the "container" `<a/>` node, loop over the books and filter as needed.

```
for $book in /a/book
where not($book/test = "love")
return <book>{ $book/@id }</book>
```

A second problem was with the `@id` attribute: To access the variable during cunstruction, you have to put curly brackets around it and access the variable, not some attribute without giving a context: `<book id="{ $id }"/>`. I used a slightly different way of constructing the element by including the attribute from the original element instead of reconstructing it.

Edit: Bonus one liner for XQuery 3.0 capable systems:

```
/a/book[not($book/test = "love")]/element book { ./@id }
```

Comment: the result still return the book="bk3"

Comment: as inside book="bk3" have other result that not "love"

Comment: The code works for me. The filter triggers if _any_ element inside book 3 equals love. Did you rund the code on exactly the input you gave in the question or any other input?

Comment: Might "love" be actually "Love"? In book 1 and 2 the word are capitalized.

Comment: it's worked perfectly ! thanks you after u sort it out